# Creating dictionary with @jitclass in @njit decorated function

Tags: python, jit, numba

We have some Python code that I would like speed up by using numba. It looks like that numba started supporting dictionaries if the types are defined, so I tried to define a dictionary in a @njit decorated class. In the code below class Counter seems to be different in the @njit decorated function because the some code raises on exception.
Do I need to pass information about class Counter into the @njit function? If so, how can I do that?

```
from numba import njit
from numba.core import types
from numba.typed import Dict
from numba.experimental import jitclass

@jitclass([
    ("value", types.int64),
])
class Counter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
 
@njit
def main():
    a = Counter()     # works, so Counter seems to be know
    dic = Dict.empty(
        key_type=types.unicode_type,
        value_type=Counter.class_type.instance_type, # raises Unknown attribute 'class_type' of type jitclass.Counter#190a6b970f0<value:int64>
    )

dic = Dict.empty(                                 # this works
    key_type=types.unicode_type,
    value_type=Counter.class_type.instance_type,
)

main()
```

Comment: [Type expression is not supported in jit functions](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.43.0/reference/pysupported.html#dict). Scratch the jitclass, there's no reason for it, simply `array_type = types.int64[:]` outside the function and then `value_type=array_type` inside the dict initialization

Comment: @NicMoetsch Thanks for mentioning this option, class Counter actually has more members not only value. Maybe I should have chosen a better name than Counter.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
See https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html:

```
@njit
def main():
    dic = dict()   # numba.typed.Dict()
    for i in range(1000):
        dic[str(i)] = Counter()
```